# More than one kill-ring in emacs

Tags: emacs, copy-paste

Is it possible, in emacs, create more than one kill ring? For example, I would like to create my alternative copy-paste commands with a secondary kill-ring in order to insert in it special portions of text, without losing the built-in kill-ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Download library [`select-sel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/second-sel.el).  If you use it in connection with either library [`browse-kill-ring+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/browse-kill-ring%2b.el) or [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) then you can use both the `kill-ring` and a ring of the *secondary selections*.

With **Icicles** you can, in addition, use `M-y` at top level to choose a selection from either ring using completion against the ring entries.  During this completion you can:

- Use `S-delete` to delete entries from the current ring
- Use `C-,` to sort the candidates to yank in different ways
- Use `C-S-return` to copy a completion candidate to the other selection ring

And with a prefix arg you can switch to completing candidates from the other ring.

Some doc:

- Library [Second Sel](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection#secondary-sel.el)
- Library [Browse Kill Ring Plus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing#browse-kill-ring+.el)
- Library [**Icicles** (code)](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#BulkIciclesDownload))